# Visual studio 2015 typescript debug

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, typescript

I use VS2015 for my Typescript project.
When I place a breakpoint in function doSmth (see screenshot below),
VS place it for a whole function and I'm not able hit statement after then.

[image]

Comment: How did you create this typescript app? Is it the HTML Application with Typescript? Do you get any output messages in your output window? http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/05/27/TypeScript-debugging-in-Visual-Studio-with-IE-Chrome-and-Firefox-using-Source-Maps.aspx

Comment: @ BigZoo, what about this issue? Would you please let me know the latest information in your side?:)

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the place where you want to place the breakpoint (in this case, the console.log statement) and select Breakpoint -> Insert Breakpoint. (This also helps for other languages like C#.)